# extract word by region from pdf file in c# using pdfpig library

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract text from a pdf file by region, using pdfpig library. This library is meant for extracting text, However I am currently unable to find any way to do so.
Please help

Comment: There is any problem with the example here: https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig ?

Comment: Please see an example in this discussion https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/discussions/306